# symfony 1 Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\config/..\lib\vendor\symfony\lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php): faile

Tags: symfony1

i moved my symfony project from one server to a seconde (linux)

when trying to lunch my project in web browser in local server i get a error

```
Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\5mondes_debugging\config/..\lib\vendor\symfony\lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\5mondes_debugging\config\ProjectConfiguration.class.php on line 4

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\5mondes_debugging\config/..\lib\vendor\symfony\lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\5mondes_debugging\config\ProjectConfiguration.class.php on line 4
```

in my config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php the path is

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/..\lib\vendor\symfony\lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
```

but canot finde sfCoreAutoload.class.php file in my project.

i will be glad for some issues

Comment: `C:\xampp\`? Are you sure it is linux?

Comment: yes et whose windows

Comment: if got fixed this thanks